# .NET 2.0 Rest Client

Tags: .net, http, .net-2.0

I am having trouble finding out if you can build a .Net 2.0 REST client. I have searched high and low but only come across results that mention using 3.5 and WCF. I would like to be able to build a .Net REST client using 2.0 if at all possible. I have a general idea of what I want to accomplish and I am running into issues passing parameters against an authenticated REST web service. I am looking for examples that are .Net 2.0 vb or c#.

I am currently trying to use HttpWebRequest but running into issues:

```
        Dim ord As order
        Dim url As String = String.Format("https://login.someurl.com/rest/order/{0}", Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(id))
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(New Uri(url))
        request.Method = "GET"
        request.ContentType = "application/json"
        request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(UserName, Password)
        Dim resp As HttpWebResponse = Nothing

        resp = request.GetResponse()
        Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream)
        Dim response As String = reader.ReadToEnd

        ord = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response)
```

Error Message I am receiving on the GetResponse() line is: "The remote server returned an error: (412) Parameter Error."

Comment: You sure the service supports json?

Comment: @dkackman positive, it is in the api documentation

Answer (score 3):

Set the accept header, not the ContentType.  The ContentType is only when you are sending data.  And just for clarification, you are not actually using WebClient, you are using the HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse objects which are a different thing altogether.

Also, make sure you install Fiddler so that you can actually see what is going across the wire.  It will make your life much easier.

Comment: good catch there, I had some left over code from tinkering with the WebClient object. I do have fiddler installed, i will look into my request from there.

Answer (score 2):

.Net 3.5 is .Net 2.0 with added libraries. just install .Net 3.5 and configure the website/WebService if using (IIS 6) or Application Pool if using IIS 7.5

Answer (score 1):

1. As a test I downloaded RestSharp. Set it to compile as .NET 2.0. Removed unresolved assemblies.
2. Then I added `LinqBridge.dll`.
   It complained about not having `System.Xml.Linq`
3. So I downloaded mono and opened the `System.Xml.Linq_net2.0.csproj`.
4. Removed the reference to `System.Core.dll`
5. Added `LinqBridge.dll`
6. Created the missing consts. file so that it had the right properties for Assembly cs file.
   And it compiled.
7. I went back to the RestSharp project and added a reference to the `System.Xml.Linq` I just created and it compiled
8. I have yet to test it but I will be doing it soon for one of my projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) instead.

> RestSharp is a simple, open source REST client for .NET designed primarily for consuming third-party HTTP APIs.

Comment: I have looked at that but i cannot use the library as it requires .Net 3.5

Comment: @Mike D - .NET 3.5 uses the 2.0 runtime. You should be able to use the binaries just fine.

Comment: @Oded, depends, if the library references .NET 3.5 assemblies such as `System.Core` it won't work. The fact that both frameworks use the same CLR doesn't mean that an assembly compiled against .NET 3.5 will run on a machine that only has .NET 2.0 installed. And looking at [RestSharp.csproj](https://github.com/johnsheehan/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/RestSharp.csproj) it seems that it requires System.Core.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - Fair point. Didn't consider 3.5 assemblies.

Comment: @Oded, yeah, it's a common gotcha, but if we have to be realistic, who the hell doesn't use **at least** .NET 3.5 at the end of 2011? And the last behemoths left probably should ask themselves some questions.

Comment: @Oded, yeah, I know that there are dinosaurs left :-) By the way the other day I was doing a code review on an ASP.NET application that was supposed to run on .NET 2.0. `var` was not available for Chris sake. I consider all .NET prior to 3.0 as total legacy code.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to build a REST client with nothing more than the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class which is available to .net 2.0.

The code associated with [this WP7 app](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows-phone-7/MyLastFm.aspx) has a simple one. Though the app itself is .net 4 I don't think that there is anything in there that would be too hard to port to .net 2 (XDocument is pretty easy to replace with XmlDocument as long as you grok XPath)

Comment: See my edit, looking for an example to help troubleshoot where my issue may lie.